# Celery Flower Is Able To Shutdown Worker But Unable To Restart It

Tags: python, django, celery, kombu, flower

I have installed Celery, Django-Celery, Kombu & Flower.

Celery Flower is monitoring fine. It is able to shutdown worker(s) but unable to restart them.

**Flower responses:**

```
[I 140903 15:49:12 web:1856] 200 GET / (127.0.0.1) 77.49ms
[I 140903 15:49:13 web:1856] 304 GET /static/img/glyphicons-halflings.png (127.0.0.1) 17.01ms
[I 140903 15:54:27 web:1856] 304 GET / (127.0.0.1) 2.91ms
[I 140903 15:54:33 control:62] Shutting down 'celery@ftp_fastq' worker
[I 140903 15:54:33 web:1856] 200 POST /api/worker/shutdown/celery%40ftp_fastq (127.0.0.1) 4.03ms
[I 140903 15:54:40 control:103] Restarting 'celery@ftp_fastq' worker's pool
[E 140903 15:54:41 control:112] []
[W 140903 15:54:41 web:1856] 403 POST /api/worker/pool/restart/celery%40ftp_fastq (127.0.0.1) 1037.44ms
```

Comment: Have you investigated your logs on the celery worker?  I'd enable debug level logging and see if anything is reporting in the workers log file.

Comment: Here is [worker log](https://gist.github.com/ChillarAnand/a1eae6feb37c6064444c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flower controls Celery remotely. So, I had to set `CELERYD_POOL_RESTARTS = True` in my config file.

You can check if `pool_restart` is enabled or not, from celery itself.

```
from celery.task.control import broadcast
broadcast('pool_restart')
```